# React environment variables disappear after login

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

Hope you're doing well :)

So I've a **.env.development** and **.env.production** files. Before login, development variables appear:

```
REACT_APP_REDIRECT=http://localhost:3000/login
REACT_APP_URL=https://something.net
```

But after login, which is after two redirects, they disappear. A console.log (process.env):

```
 {NODE_ENV: "development", PUBLIC_URL: "", WDS_SOCKET_HOST: undefined, WDS_SOCKET_PATH: undefined, WDS_SOCKET_PORT: undefined, …}
    FAST_REFRESH: true
    NODE_ENV: "development"
    PUBLIC_URL: ""
    WDS_SOCKET_HOST: undefined
    WDS_SOCKET_PATH: undefined
    WDS_SOCKET_PORT: undefined
    __proto__: Object
```

Both .env files are in the root folder and don't have invalid parameters. I don't understand why this happens...
Does anyone understand why? :)

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out. I still don't understand why this happens, must have something to do with session data or so. I've set them in sessionStorage and fetch them after. Like this:

```
let setEnvVariablesToSessionStorage = () => {
  sessionStorage.setItem("urlRedirect", process.env.REACT_APP_REDIRECT);
  sessionStorage.setItem("baseURL", process.env.REACT_APP_URL);
};
setEnvVariablesToSessionStorage();
```

In auth.js : `export const urlRedirect = sessionStorage.getItem("urlRedirect");`
In http.js: `export const baseURL = sessionStorage.getItem("baseURL");`

Happy coding! :)